# Какую модель использовать для предсказания расхода деталей?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, keras

У меня есть данные для 500 деталей в виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача по ним предсказать расход на 2024 (соотвественно обучить модель на прошлых годах).
Я делаю Label Encoder для групп и для названий деталей.

На вход моделям данные поступают в таком виде:

'comp_names','New_group', 'mean_eq',  '2015', '2016','2017', '2018', '2019','2020','2021'.

comp_names - encoder для названий;
New_group - encoder для группы;

Проверочные данные:
'comp_names','New_group', 'mean_eq', '2014', '2015', '2016','2017', '2018', '2019','2020'.

Далее я попробовал нармолизовать данные MinMaxScaler и тестировал модели с ним и без него.
Я попробовал Линейную регрессию

```
model_lr = LinearRegression()
model_lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model_lr.predict(X_test)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
print('MSE:', mse)
```

CatBoostRegressor

```
gb = CatBoostRegressor()
gb.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Также нейронную сеть

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(9,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
```

Подгтовка данных:

1. Предварительно отчильтрованы пустые значения
2. Названия деталей тоже преведены к общему виду (один регистр, убрал окончания, отчистил от лишних символов)
3. Разбивка данных:

- пробовал разбивать данные по строкам и давать их на вход

```py
data_for_predict = df_filtered[['New_group', 'mean_eq',  '2015', '2016','2017', '2018', '2019','2020','2021']].values
data_for_test = df_filtered[['New_group', 'mean_eq', '2016','2017','2018', '2019','2020','2021','2022']].values
data_for_val = df_filtered[['New_group', 'mean_eq', '2014','2015','2016','2017','2018', '2019','2020',]].values
//блок выше использовал для разбивки по колонкам
scaler_x = MinMaxScaler()
scaler_y = MinMaxScaler()
norm_data_x = scaler_x.fit_transform(data_for_predict)
norm_data_y = scaler_y.fit_transform(df_filtered['2022'].values.reshape(-1,1))
// с помощью 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_for_predict, df_filtered['2022'], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
X1_train, X1_test, y1_train, y1_test = train_test_split(norm_data_x, norm_data_y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

- пробовал разбивать данные по столбцам (2014..2020 для тренировочного и 2015-2021 для тестового)

Но по всем этим моделям предсказания довольно плохие. R2 score не выше 0.5.

1. Возможно ли вообще с таким набором сделать качественный прогноз?
2. Как стоит преобразовать данные, чтобы улучшить предсказание.
   Есть мысли по поводу сумирования расхода за прошлые года и давая это как параметр.
   Сделать таблицу, где будет столбец год а в строках расход деталей по годам.

DS example:

```
Group   Name    Количество оборудования где установлена деталь/ Сумму установленных деталей Год1    Год2    Год3    Год4    Год5    Год6    Год7    Год8    Год9    Год10   Год11   Год12   Год13
o   FIBER,OPTIC SENSOR  100%    0   0   0   0   0   3   1   0   2   1   0   0   2
ax  AUXILIARY CONTACT BLOCK 3S+ 67% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
md  MODULE-DIAGNOSIS    100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   1
0   VACUUMPUMP  100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   1
sw  BNS260-11ZG 83% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
co  SIGNALLING COLUMN MULTI 100%    0   0   0   2   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   5   2
mo  MOTOR   100%    0   0   0   0   1   3   3   2   0   0   0   0   1
como    Terminal    100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   1   2
pow STROBOSCOPE 100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
0   key     100%    1   3   8   2   4   7   4   3   4   1   3   1   4
re  DIOsDE  67% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
con CONNECTOR   100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
b   BATTfERY    50% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
m   MAGNET I    78% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   1   2   1
m   SWITCH MAGN 100%    0   0   0   0   1   1   1   2   1   0   0   0   1
sw  PROX SWITCH 100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   2   1   5   3
cb  Miniature circuit breaker   100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
sw  PROX    100%    0   0   0   0   2   0   0   2   1   1   0   2   1
co  ROUND ANGLE     100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
    Continuous      100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
sw  PRESSURE    100%    0   0   0   2   3   0   4   3   7   4   4   10  5
un  RANSMISSIVE 100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   3   1   1
pow POWER   100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
md  BLOWER  100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   2
cp  CPU 100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
mo  MOTOR   100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   2
u   UNIT    100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
a   AU  48% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
cb  CIRCUIT 100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
com MODULE TERMINAL 18% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
com MODULE TERMINAL 100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
com MODULE TERMINAL 46% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
com MODULE TERMINAL 33% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
com MODULE TERMINAL 100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
di  DI IN   100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
di  DI IN   100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
di  DI on   100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
ai  imd 100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
con FRONT   100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
con Conmd   100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
con conid   67% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
com Terminal    25% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
prf coup    100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
ai  inoee   100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
pw  POWER   60% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
p   photo   100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
do  do  100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
di  di  55% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
be  bwck    100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
md  mda 100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
op  opto    67% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
sa  safety module   50% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
do  do  100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
c   CPU 100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
do  el  100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
pow pow 100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
com mda 100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
do  ter 100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
ai  imnp    100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
sa  cont    67% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
cf  sped    50% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
do  el  100%    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
ma  act 78% 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Не могу воспользоваться kaggle , github или google drive (политика компании)
В данных изменил названия и цифры, общие закономености сохранил.

Описание данных:
Каждая строка соответствует уникальному компоненту, есть конечно компоненты с похожим названием и целью, но суть в том, что одна строчка один компонент.

Comment: С виду данные выглядят довольно случайными, по крайней мере те, которые вы показали. А вообще мне кажется вам надо в сторону `time series` смотреть, а не просто года как фичи в модель скармливать. И вот в этом разрезе наверное имело бы смысл скормить модели какие-то аггрегации за разные промежутки времени. Например, среднее или сумму по самой детали и по группе деталей за 1-2-3-4-5-... лет. Имеет смысл нагенерить много таких агрегатов, а потом попробовать их скормить разным моделям и посмотреть - появился ли сигнал и какие из агрегатов "взлетели", а какие нет. Возможна сезонность по годам.

Comment: `LogisticRegression` не смотря на название это не регрессия, это классификация, она для вашей задачи не подходит.

Comment: Ещё раз посмотрел на данные. Наилучшее предсказание по вашим данным будет просто `0` для любой детали и любого года. Ничего лучше этого вы никакой самой хитрой нейросетью тут не придумаете. Сигнала тут нет, сплошной рандом. А вообще `R2 = 0.5` - это довольно хороший скор. Я бы хотел посмотреть тренировочные данные и предсказание, на которых вы этот результат получили. )

Comment: К сожалению данными не смогу поделиться, а получил такой скор как раз с нейронкой Dense 64 - Dropout 0.3 и нормализованными данными MinMax

Comment: Дайте данные хотя бы по десятку позиций. И поменяйте чувствительную информацию: вместо реальных названий вбейте какую-то галиматью, и данные местами поменяйте - перенесите цифры туда-сюда, слегка их поменяйте. Этого будет достаточно для анализа. А совсем без данных вам тут вряд ли помогут. И покажите точный код, как вы данные готовили. Я не исключаю, что у вас просто "утечка данных" - предсказание по тем же данным, которые модель уже видела. Для достаточно сложной нейросети нет проблемы просто даже запомнить все данные.

Comment: Я правильно понял,  что у вас количество деталей за год измеряется в штуках? И в основном везде нули? О каком качественном прогнозе тогда может идти речь?

Comment: Как уже сказали - во-первых, по такому количеству данных предсказать расход крайне проблематично, во-вторых, это явные временные ряды. Исходя из этого, я бы применял для начала не простые временные ряды, а ряды событий. Т.е. просто бы пытался предсказать, а надо-ли вообще будет в 2024 году делать закупку некоторого оборудования. Соответственно, рыл бы в сторону процессов Пуассона и экспоненциального распределения.

Comment: @AlexAlex Теоретически, даже при таких условиях там могла быть некая периодичность в данных, позволяющая хоть что-то предсказать, но я её там не вижу. Чисто "out of the blue" все циферки выглядят, никакой системы.

Comment: Хорошо, что показали данные. Пока могу сказать, что подготовка данных всё-таки у вас несколько хромает. Почитайте всё же про предсказание временных рядов. Сейчас вы по части позиций за 2022 год пытаетесь предсказать остальные позиции за 2022 год. Это так не работает. Когда вы делаете прогноз на 2024 год у вас нет никаких данных на 2024 год. Трейн-тест для временных рядов бьётся иным образом: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/_images/sphx_glr_plot_cv_indices_013.png

Comment: Но вообще, повторюсь, лучше переходите на аггрегаты. Вернее, по-хорошему у вас должны быть фичи типа текущий_год, год-1, год-2, год-3, ..., среднее за последние 2 года, среднее за последние 3 года, ... и таргет - следующий год. Учитесь вы так, что следующий год у вас, например, 2021 и фичи соответственно за 2020 и т.д., а предсказываете когда, то таргет у вас 2022, а фичи за 2021 и т.д., именно относительные текущего года (типа год-1), а не абсолютные. Это сложно объяснить с первого раза, проще если вы почитаете какие-то материалы сами. Трейн: 2010-2020 -> 2021. Предсказание:2011-2021 -> 2022

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо, буду пробовать! 
Не подскажите литературу, чтобы углубить знания в подготовке данных и про предсказания временных рядов?

Comment: @Donny_darko Тема непростая. Хотел дать ссылку на свой репозиторий с одного соревнования, а я там задачу на временные ряды так и не оформил и не выложил, оказывается. А так даже не знаю, что предложить, погуглите на тему `time series python`, посмотрите, что вам из найденного понятнее будет.